# JQuery .each function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand why the following doesn't work:

```
function SetMaxLength() {
    var form = $("body").find("form");
    form.each(function () {
        var elements = $(this).find("input");
        elements.each(function() {
            var attr = $(this).attr('data-val-maxlength-max');
            if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
                $(this).attr('maxlength', attr.value);
            }
        });
    });
}


<form action="/go/somewhere" autocomplete="off" class="form-one" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate"> 
  <input data-val-maxlength="Invalid Email" data-val-maxlength-max="254" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

when I step through it, it finds 1 form but then on the each part it just skips it, steps over it.

Basically all it is suppose to do it when it sees `data-val-maxlength-max` attribute, it is suppose to take its value and inject `maxlength` attribute in the element.

JsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/j04vue8r/3/

Comment: You only have one `<form>` so your live demo isn't reproducing your problem, and you never call the function, so it won't run because you're not telling it to do so. That said, is this what you're wanting: https://jsfiddle.net/j04vue8r/4/

Comment: @DavidThomas missed that part in the fiddle, I updated the fiddle

Comment: @DavidThomas are you saying that the reason each is not working is because it only finds one form?

Comment: It only finds one form because there is only one form (in your demo). I've updated the demo (linked in my previous comment) to show a more concise means of achieving what I think you're after, which should theoretically work with multiple forms.

Comment: Can you try `$(form).each`

Comment: your demo works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have jQuery included in your page, it's better to rewrite your code and make it more "**jQuery style**".

Here we go:

```js
$('[data-val-maxlength-max]').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('maxlength', $(this).data('val-maxlength-max'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/go/somewhere" autocomplete="off" class="form-one" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate"> 
  <input data-val-maxlength="Invalid Email" data-val-maxlength-max="254" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it not step over the each function. The problem is  the `attr()` function that doesn't set the maxlenght attribute because you have a mistake in the code: attr is just the value of `data-val-maxlength-max` and so you have to write something like this:

```
$(this).attr('maxlength', attr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you need:

```
$(function() {
  $("form input").each(function() {
    var attr = $(this).attr('data-val-maxlength-max');
    if (typeof attr !== undefined && attr !== false) {
        $(this).attr('maxlength', attr);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with above code.
1. Function SetMaxLength is not called
2. variable attr already contains value. So you don't need to do attr.value

Below code works

```
function SetMaxLength() {
var form = $("body").find("form");
form.each(function () {
    var elements = $(this).find("input");
    elements.each(function() {
        var attr = $(this).attr('data-val-maxlength-max');
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            $(this).attr('maxlength', attr);
        }
    });
});
```

}
SetMaxLength()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   window.onload = function () {
    SetMaxLength(); 
}

function SetMaxLength() {

    var form = $("body").find("form");

    form.each(function () {

        var elements = $(this).find("input");

        elements.each(function() {
            var attr = $(this).attr('data-val-maxlength-max');
            console.log(attr);
            if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
                $(this).attr('maxlength', attr);
            }
        });

    });

}
```

All I did was remove `attr.value` in your if statement. Works fine for me. You don't need the value, since you already grabbed it in the variable : ). I'd encourage you not to use generic terms like "form" and "elements" and "attr". They might cause issues.

By the way, in the future you may wish to use console.log. It helped me figure out the issue here. I did `console.log(attr)` right after the `var attr`line to see what we were getting. In Chrome you can view the console by hitting ctrl + shift + J. Since I saw that it was 254, I knew we didn't need to get a new value : ).